# Windows Phone: non-standard libraries

Tags: windows-phone-7, libraries

I need to use specific classes in Windows Phone application: `GzipStream` and `JpegImageDecoder`. I can find documentation for them on msdn.com, but in Visual Studio, in Windows Phone application they are inaccessible.
How to use them?

Comment: What functionality do you need from `JpegImageDecoder`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get GzipStream as a part of [SharpZipLib](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/SharpZipLib) from [NuGet](http://nuget.org/).

To use JpegImageDecoder, you will have to just find it's .net implementation (if one exists) and include it into your project.